# Besides Rails, what are other popular web dev tools, frameworks, libs for Ruby?

Tags: ruby

ORMs, HTML Templates, URL mappers? I'm new to Ruby and I'm wondering what other options are there for web development other than Rails.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe [sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/)?

Answer (score 3):

You can get some information on these and many other topics at [Ruby Toolbox](http://ruby-toolbox.com/):

- [Web App Frameworks](http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/web_app_frameworks.html)
- [Template Languages](http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/template_languages.html)

I'm not sure what "URL mappers" in your question refers to, however.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to recommend [Padrino](http://www.padrinorb.com/). It's an easy framework to get started with, and the documentation is great.

Cut from the Padrino webpage:

> Padrino is a ruby framework built upon the excellent Sinatra Microframework. Sinatra is a DSL for quickly creating simple web applications in Ruby. Padrino was created to make it fun and easy to code more advanced web applications while still adhering to the spirit that makes Sinatra great!

Answer (score 1):

Would [Watir](http://watir.com/) count?  [10 Alternative Ruby Web Frameworks](http://accidentaltechnologist.com/ruby/10-alternative-ruby-web-frameworks/) has a list of other possibilities to explore.